# make ibuffer-visit-buffer behave like ido-switch-to-buffer?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a way to make `ibuffer-visit-buffer` behave like `ido-switch-to-buffer` (with raise-frame option)? If there is a window/frame containing the buffer I'd like emacs to take me there rather than opening the same buffer in the current window. I guess `switch-to-buffer` is remapped to `ido-switch-to-buffer` when `ido-mode` is turned on, so would doing something like that work in this case (remap `ibuffer-visit-buffer` to `ido-switch-to-buffer`)? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is absolutely correct - ido-mode remaps switch-to-buffer (and some others) via minor-mode map.

I don't see any problem doing the same for your function.